# Vis-Viva equation applied to Earth

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit

We know that the Vis-Viva equation is given by:

$v=\sqrt{G M\left(\frac{2}{r}-\frac{1}{a}\right)}$

If I plug-in the values for Earth (the mass is obviously that of the Sun):

$G=6.6743 \times 10^{-11} \mathrm{~m}^3 \mathrm{~kg}^{-1} \mathrm{~s}^{-2}$

$M_\circ=3.955 \times 10^{30} \mathrm{~kg}$

$a=149.60\times 10^9 \mathrm{~m}$

and I calculate it for $r=a$ I get a result that looks quite false:

$v=\sqrt{G M\left(\frac{2}{r}-\frac{1}{a}\right)}=1.33\mathrm{~km}\mathrm{~s}^{-1}$

when the average orbital speed for Earth is known to be $30\mathrm{~km}\mathrm{~s}^{-1}$.

I don't get it... Did I type a value wrong in my calculator or is it just that I applied the Vis-Viva equation wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Uhoh mentioned you had the wrong mass for the sun and I went to look at that. According to https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/sunfact.html it's about 1.98x10^30 kg, as Uhoh showed. But if you google "What is the mass of the sun?", the top of the page is big bold letters that say "3.955 × 10^30 kg", your exact value.  So I think Google is somehow screwy and returning nearly twice the correct value.

Comment: Hilariously, directly below that, Google helpfully shows that value as also "1.988 M☉", acknowledging that it just told you the mass of the sun is 1.988 solar masses.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym Wow, that's messed up.

Answer (score 11):

With $r = a$ for a circle, you're ([correct!](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/64947/12102)) equation simplifies to

$$ v = \sqrt{\frac{GM}{a}}$$

which using a different mass for the Sun than you used, gives the right answer. I used

```
G = 6.674E-11
M = 1.9885E+30
a = 150E+09
```

with the same units as yours, and got v = 29744.7 m/s.

The fairly small difference for the Solar mass can't account for your very large numerical error; I think you also made some arithmetic error somewhere.

**However:** If you forgot three zeros somewhere, your wrong solar mass plus a factor of $\sqrt{1/1000}$ does indeed give 1326.5 m/s!!

---

[image: orbital speed of the earth quickie]

---

**note:** In the future, use the [standard gravitational parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravitational_parameter) (the product $GM$) instead of $G$ and $M$ separately. We can measure solar system velocities and distances to great accuracy, and those give us the $GM$ product to high accuracy. But measuring either one separately is a lot harder, so the uncertainty on those numbers is much larger.

Comment: Great answer! When I did some orbital trajectory calculations, I always used G and M as separate variable. The standard gravitational parameter definitely makes things a lot easier and helps me avoid simple mistakes.

Comment: @TheRocketfan We only know G to 4 and a bit digits. So it's always better to use the gravitational parameter, if you have that option. This page has Solar System GM values that are consistent with JPL DE 440: https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/astro_par.html

Comment: @PM2Ring indeed! [Where to find the best values for standard gravitational parameters of solar system bodies?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22948/12102)